# Grep files with `<?` (not `<?php`)

Tags: regex, grep

Just a simple question. How can I find (recursively) all files containing `<?` (and not `<?php`)?

Thanks!
Kevin

Comment: Is this a homework? Can you use awk?

Comment: No, no homework ;). Yes, awk is installed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `--perl-regexp` flag so you can use a more powerful perl-compatible regex with a negative lookahead:

```
grep -Prl '<\?(?!php)' .
```

Comment: Thanks! :) And how can I fetch files also fullfulling `<?[^a-z]{1,}`? Because this will also fetch `<?xml`.

Comment: Just noticed you wanted to find the files that match, so I added the `-l` flag (`--files-with-matches`).

Comment: So you want to fetch files with `<?` not followed by "php", "xml", or any letters? If I understand that correctly, you just want `<\?(?![a-z])`.

Answer (score 0):

The regex you want is `<\?(?!php)`

Comment: `grep -rl '<\?(?!php)' /var/www/vhosts` has 0 results :(.. And I'm sure there is at least one file fullfilling the statement.

Answer (score 0):

Well

```
 grep -r \<\? SomeDir
```

will catch all occurrences of `<?` (and you could have used `fgrep`)

Then, you want to remove all occurrences of php. You might use

```
grep -r \<\? SomeDir | grep -v php
```

which should give you a good enough approximation (but is a bit wrong, because it would skip lines containing  `<?`  and `php` not together). You could replace the second `grep` with an `awk` or a `cut` to print the file name.

You might also use

```
grep -rl `<\?[^p][^h]`
```